# Efficient algorithm to step through all of linked list (in C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, linked-list

Suppose I have a doubly-linked list, with a byte associated with each element.  Wikipedia has a good visual; pretend the numbers are hexadecimal numbers:

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5e/Doubly-linked-list.svg/500px-Doubly-linked-list.svg.png]

Now, the naïve ("immediately obvious") way to build a string from the list, given a pointer to the last node in the string (in this example, the `37` node), is:

```
using std::string;

string node::makeString()
{
  return this->prev->makeString() + this->data;
}
```

The goal is the string `"\0x12\0x99\0x37"`.  However, this function requires lots of reallocations of the string being built and lots of function call overhead (it can't be tail-call optimized); doubtless there are other inefficiences that I'm not aware of.

Is there a better way?  Of course, I'm not just looking to minimize theoretical time complexity; I'm really trying to find a method that will be fastest *in practice*.

Comment: That solution is actually quite bad... one function call per character added to the actual cost of building the string.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said it was naïve ;)

Comment: Not just naïve... naïve would have been to iterate in a loop adding each character. That looks like a poor functional approach (poor in that it does not allow for tail recursion optimizations)

Comment: Tail call optimization would be very clean... is there a way to do that?

Comment: An efficient solution would be to use a sentinel node (your `[X]`) which links end and begin.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: that's not naive solution. it is solution written by somebody who is used to tail recursion - somebody with a bit of functional programming experience could write something like that.

Comment: @SigTerm: Except that it is not *tail-recursion*... close, but not the same

Comment: Tail recursion (but not what I would do): `void build(Node *ptr, std::string& str) { if (ptr!=nullptr) { str.append(ptr->data); build(ptr->next,str); } }`.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Technically, you removed syntax sugar (operator+) and passed by reference instead of value. The call pattern is the same. Check tail-recursive examples for scheme or lisp and compare with OPs code. You'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: @SigTerm: No. There is a **huge** difference. For a function to be tail-recursive, control must *not* continue after the recursive function call. In the code in the question the caller must return to perform `operator+` making it not tail recursive. The fact that the code never returns to the function doing the recursive call is important. The fact that the control never goes back to the caller implies that the stack can be reused, no state of the caller needs to be maintained for the function to come back to. That is tail-recursion.

Comment: stack overflow called, he says : see you in 10k charachters :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the empty `std::string`, walk back to the front of the list, then loop through the nodes and `push_back` onto the string. That takes linear time, which is optimal for this problem.

Further optimizations are possible if you know up front how long the list is. In that case, you can start with a string of the appropriate length and insert characters into it directly.

Comment: `std::string` has `push_back`, has the same complexity requirements, and has the added benefit of "saying what you mean".

Comment: Why is a `std::vector` superior to a `std::string`? (EDIT: Ah, I've been sniped by @BoBTFish; seems that it isn't.)

Comment: @BoBTFish: good point. I seldom use `std::string`, because I use C++ mostly for numerical work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way?

Sure.

1. Locate beginning of the list. *While locating beginning of the list*, count total number of nodes (if it isn't already available) and **calculate total string size** for final string.
2. **Preallocate** string of required size using `std::string::reserve()`
3. Walk through the list from first node to the last, adding data to the end of previously preallocated string. You can use `std::string::append()` for that.

Comment: Is this faster than @JerryCoffin's answer?  He says to build the string backward, then reverse it.  Sure, they have the same big-O complexity, but which one, in practice, would be faster?

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: I think it's likely to depend on the length of the list/string in question. If it's small enough to all fit in cache, then the second time through the list will be really cheap, so it may well pay off. If it's long enough that you read most of the list from memory twice, that's likely to lose to (a few) possible reallocations.

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: JerryCoffin doesn't mention "reserve". Without reserve you'll trigger several reallocations while appending new strings. Also building string backwards (although it is reasonable idea) might not exactly be easy depending on your data. If source data is not string and needs to be converted into string, then c++ formatting functions do not produce "reversed" strings (which means, there will be extra operations).

Answer (score 1):

Given the constraints at hand (that you're basically stuck walking the list in reverse), it's probably best to build the string in reverse as well, then when all the characters have been added, reverse the string.

<strike>The way you're doing things right now you're getting quadratic complexity -- every time you insert another character, put that character into a string, the copy all the existing characters to the new string, so each insertion is linear and N insertions is roughly O(N<sup>2</sup>).</strike>[Note: actually, I'd misread the code -- it's bad, but not quite this bad] As it is right now, we can expect every character to be copied at least twice -- once to the stack, and once to the destination string. The inefficiency is probably most apparent if you think in terms of memory bandwidth. At bare minimum, each call has to read a pointer, write the current character to the stack and write a return address, all to copy one byte from the linked list to the destination string. Assuming a 64-bit implementation, we're looking at a ratio of something like 18:1 in terms of reading and writing pointers (and other overhead) vs. copying the data we actually care about.

By building the string backward, then reversing it, you add new characters at the end of the string, where you can expect it to happen quickly. Then you do all that extra moving only once instead of once for every character you add.

If you were using `std::vector<char>`, you could state categorically that adding a character at the end of the string was amortized constant complexity. With `std::string` we don't (that I recall) get a complexity guarantee, but it would take an amazingly terrible implementation for it to be as bad as a recursive call just to copy one character.

Another possibility would be to use an `std::deque<char>` instead of a `string`. With a deque, you can insert characters at the front without moving all the other characters to make room. This does have two shortcomings: the result isn't (normally) a contiguous block of memory, and you typically get an extra level of indirection, so access to the data after it's built is marginally slower.

Comment: Ultimately, I will be templatizing this if I can; so I may not have a choice which container I'm using.  Which approach would be compatible with the most number of containers?  (I can specialize if it will help amazingly with speed.)

Comment: @thirtythreeforty: The first (build backwards, then reverse) is the clear choice for container independence. The latter depends entirely upon a container that has fast insertion at the front, so it can't work with `string` or `vector`, which are probably the two most likely/common targets.

Comment: I'd also like to point out that this works equally well for a tree, starting from a leaf.  (Walking up, then back down works for a list, but not a tree, unless you use recursion.)  I think I like this approach the best.

Answer (score 0):

The inefficiency in your solution is due to the recursion. For a linked list, set up a string and use a simple while loop. This will lead to better performance, as there will not be the overhead of one function call per string.

```
string makeString() {
  Node* p = l.end(); //l is the linked list. end is its tail node
  string s = "";
  while(p != NULL) {
    s = p.value() + s; //append the value to the string
    p = p.prev(); //advance p to the prev node
  }
  return s;
}
```

Of course for even better performance, I would consider not using a linked data structure as they can lead to inefficiencies dealing with locality in memory.

Comment: There is not a "container" that contains a pointer to the head node.

Comment: sorry, fixed. And these are approximate calls. You have to modify to your code as we don't have access to your whole code.

Comment: also, you will need to move makeString outside of the node class to implement this in a more efficient way.

Comment: Why does moving it outside the class matter?

Comment: You probably wouldn't need to, but it might make a little more sense given the context. Both approaches can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd create a linked list of strings, or rather, char arrays, and then fill each node in backwards.

```
struct StringNode
{
  char buffer [20];
  struct StringNode *next;
};

StringNode *node = new StringNode;
node->buffer [19] = '\0';
node->next = 0;
size_t output = 18;
size_t count = 1;

for (ptr = last item ; ptr ; ptr = ptr->prev)
{
  node->buffer [output] = ptr->character;
  ++count;
  if (output)
  {
    --output;
  }
  else
  {
    StringNode *newnode = new StringNode;
    newnode->buffer [19] = '\0';
    newnode->next = node;
    output = 18;
    node = newnode;
  }
}

string output (count); // preallocate enough storage for whole string and initialise to an empty string

while(node)
{
  output += &node->buffer [output+1];
  // or: cout << &node->buffer [output+1];
  StringNode *nextnode = node->next;
  delete node;
  node = nextnode;
  output = -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bottle-neck is reallocating the string. So I would firstly count the number of nodes and after that I would build the string. For example

```
std::string::size_type n = 1;
for ( ; node->prev; node = node->prev ) ++n;
std::string s;
s.reserve( n );
for ( ; node->next; node = node->next ) s.push_back( node->data );
```

Comment: And that's why the C++ `std::list` class has an O(1) `.size()` member.

Comment: However this list in the assignment has only three members: prev, next and data. It even has nither head nor tail.:)

Comment: @MSalters Hmmm, adding a `height` member might solve the issue for me, then.